# Recycler View items not changing. NotifyDataSetChanged is not working

Tags: android, header, adapter, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am developing an android application which shows list of items available for sale. I am using `recycler view` to display the list. I have a header for the `recycler view` and the header has 3 `buttons` for 3 categories (all, veg, non veg) and also meal type (breakfast/snacks).
And I have a bottom bar below the `recycler view` that has a `button` to show cart. Pressing that `button` opens another `activity` that list all the items in the cart.

User can increase or decrease the quantity of the item from the cart.
When user comes back from cart to menu page after modifying the contents of the cart(increasing/decreasing the quantities),sometimes the same quantity doesn't reflect on the menu page. I am notifying the `adapter` when user comes from cart to menu page. It gets changed after I scroll the list.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<MenuDescription> listOrder, DatabaseHandlerForCartAndMenu db,
                           List<MenuDescription> vegList, List<MenuDescription> nonVegList,
                           Tracker tracker, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mealTypeList,
                           ArrayList<MenuDescription> firstMealTypeList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.context = context;
    this.db = db;
    this.listOrder = firstMealTypeList;
    this.vegList = vegList;
    this.nonVegList = nonVegList;
    this.completeList = firstMealTypeList;
    this.tracker = tracker;
    this.mealTypeList = mealTypeList;
    this.globalList = listOrder;
    mealTypeViewArray = new View[mealTypeList.size()];
    previous_meal_type_id = mealTypeList.get(0).get(Constants.MEALTYPE_MENUID);
    first_date = mealTypeList.get(0).get(Constants.DATE);
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    nothingForThisCategory = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Nothing is present for this category", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, parent, false);
        menuList = view;
        return new CustomViewHolder(view, viewType);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        return new CustomViewHolder(view, viewType);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        if (holder.HolderId == 1) {

            if (nothingForThisCategory.isShown())
                nothingForThisCategory.dismiss();
            final MenuDescription menu = listOrder.get(position - 1);
            if (menu.getAvailable() >= 1) {
                holder.addSubtractButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.overlayView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.soldOutText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.addSubtractButtonsLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.overlayView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.soldOutText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            if (menu.getDecr_button_visibility() == 1) {
                holder.addSubtractLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                holder.addSubtractLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            holder.title.setText(menu.getName() + "");
            holder.price.setText(menu.getPrice() + "");
            holder.quant.setText(menu.getQuantity() + "");
            holder.description.setText(menu.getDescription());

            try {
                Glide.with(context).load(menu.getImage_path()).placeholder(R.drawable.v3_placeholder_image).fitCenter().into(holder.image);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        tx = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.total);
                        totalPrice = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);

                        menu.setDecr_button_visibility(1);
                        Constants.total_items_in_cart++;

                        Constants.total_price_of_cart += menu.getPrice();
                        totalPrice.setText(Constants.total_price_of_cart + "");

                        tx.setText(Constants.total_items_in_cart + "");

                        try {
                            if (!db.CheckIsItemAlreadyInDBorNot(menu.getItem_id(), "cart", menu.getMenu_id())) {
                                menu.incrQuantity();
                                db.addDataToCartTable(menu);
                                // cart_items.add(menu);

                                holder.quant.setText(menu.getQuantity() + "");
                            } else {
                                menu.incrQuantity();
                                db.updateQuantityInCartTable(menu.getQuantity(), menu.getItem_id(), menu.getMenu_id());
                                holder.quant.setText(menu.getQuantity() + "");
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        holder.addSubtractLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (Constants.total_items_in_cart == 1) {
                            RecyclerViewMainActivity.bottomBarUp();
                        }
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

            holder.incrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        tx = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.total);
                        totalPrice = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);

                        menu.setDecr_button_visibility(1);

                        Constants.total_items_in_cart++;

                        Constants.total_price_of_cart += menu.getPrice();
                        totalPrice.setText(Constants.total_price_of_cart + "");

                        tx.setText(Constants.total_items_in_cart + "");

                        try {
                            if (!db.CheckIsItemAlreadyInDBorNot(menu.getItem_id(), "cart", menu.getMenu_id())) {
                                menu.incrQuantity();
                                db.addDataToCartTable(menu);
                                holder.quant.setText(menu.getQuantity() + "");
                            } else {
                                menu.incrQuantity();
                                db.updateQuantityInCartTable(menu.getQuantity(), menu.getItem_id(), menu.getMenu_id());
                                holder.quant.setText(menu.getQuantity() + "");
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

            holder.decrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        tx = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.total);
                        totalPrice = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);

                        int qu = menu.getQuantity();
                        if (qu > 0) {

                            if (Constants.total_items_in_cart > 0) {
                                Constants.total_items_in_cart--;
                                tx.setText(Constants.total_items_in_cart + "");
                                Constants.total_price_of_cart -= menu.getPrice();
                                totalPrice.setText(Constants.total_price_of_cart + "");
                            }
                            if (Constants.total_items_in_cart == 0) {
                                RecyclerViewMainActivity.bottomBarDown();
                            }

                            menu.decrQuantity();
                            if (menu.getQuantity() == 0) {
                                holder.addSubtractLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                menu.setDecr_button_visibility(0);
                                try {
                                    db.DeleteCartItem(menu.getItem_id(), menu.getMenu_id());
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } else {
                                try {
                                    db.updateQuantityInCartTable(menu.getQuantity(), menu.getItem_id(), menu.getMenu_id());
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            holder.quant.setText(menu.getQuantity() + "");
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                }
            });
        } else if (holder.HolderId == TYPE_HEADER) {

            final LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < mealTypeList.size(); i++) {
                    if (!mealTypeList.get(i).get(Constants.DATE).equals(first_date))
                        date_drop_down_clickable = true;
                }
                if (!date_drop_down_clickable)
                    holder.dateDropDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                else holder.dateDropDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            String frmDateStr;
            try {
                if (Constants.dateClickedFirstTimeByDefault) {
                    if (!Constants.dateSelected.equals("")) {
                        dateClicked(Constants.dateSelected);
                        previous_meal_type_id = "";
                        mealTypeClicked(mealTypeIdSelectedBeforeCartOpened, indexBeforeCartOpened);
                    } else {
                        String dateString = mealTypeList.get(0).get(Constants.DATE);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US);
                        Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
                        frmDateStr = getFormattedDate(date);
                        AttributedString as1 = new AttributedString(frmDateStr);
                        as1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 2, 3);
                        holder.displaying_date.setText(frmDateStr);
                        dateClicked(dateString);
                    }
                    Constants.dateClickedFirstTimeByDefault = false;
                }
                if (Constants.keepAddingButtonOnCartPageClicked) {
                    Constants.keepAddingButtonOnCartPageClicked = false;
                    previous_meal_type_id = "";
                    mealTypeClicked(mealTypeIdSelectedBeforeCartOpened, indexBeforeCartOpened);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.dateDropDownLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (date_drop_down_clickable) {
                        if (holder.horizontalScrollViewDateLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                            holder.dateDropDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.pullup_red);
                            holder.horizontalScrollViewDateLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.dateLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
                            String previousDate = "";
                            int day = 0;
                            for (int i = 0; i < mealTypeList.size(); i++) {
                                if (!previousDate.equals(mealTypeList.get(i).get(Constants.DATE))) {
                                    previousDate = mealTypeList.get(i).get(Constants.DATE);
                                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US);
                                    try {
                                        Date date = sdf.parse(previousDate);
                                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                                        cal.setTime(date);
                                        day = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
                                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    View dateView = vi.inflate(R.layout.date_layout, null);
                                    final TextView dateTextView = (TextView) dateView.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
                                    if (day / 10 == 0)
                                        dateTextView.setText("0" + Integer.toString(day));
                                    else dateTextView.setText(Integer.toString(day));
                                    dateTextView.setTag(previousDate);
                                    if (i == previous_date_selected) {
                                        dateTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_button_add);
                                        dateTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                    } else {
                                        dateTextView.setBackgroundResource(0);
                                        dateTextView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Description));
                                    }
                                    holder.dateLinearLayout.addView(dateView);

                                    final String finalPreviousDate = previousDate;
                                    final int finalI = i;
                                    dateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                            holder.horizontalScrollViewDateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            holder.dateDropDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.dropdown_red);
                                            try {
                                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.US);
                                                Date date = sdf.parse(dateTextView.getTag().toString());
                                                String formattedDate = getFormattedDate(date);
                                                AttributedString as1 = new AttributedString(formattedDate);
                                                as1.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT, TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT_SUPER, 2, 3);
                                                holder.displaying_date.setText(formattedDate);
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                            }
                                            previous_date_selected = finalI;
                                            dateClicked(finalPreviousDate);
                                            addingMealTypeLayoutToUI(holder, vi);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            holder.horizontalScrollViewDateLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            holder.dateDropDown.setImageResource(R.drawable.dropdown_red);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            addingMealTypeLayoutToUI(holder, vi);

            holder.all.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listOrder = completeList;
                    if (nothingForThisCategory.isShown())
                        nothingForThisCategory.dismiss();
                    if (listOrder.size() == 0) {
                        nothingForThisCategory = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Nothing is present for this category", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        nothingForThisCategory.show();
                    }
                    previous_filter_selected = 0;
                    if (holder.buttonLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        holder.buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            holder.veg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listOrder = vegList;
                    if (nothingForThisCategory.isShown())
                        nothingForThisCategory.dismiss();
                    if (listOrder.size() == 0) {
                        nothingForThisCategory = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Nothing is present for this category", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        nothingForThisCategory.show();
                    }
                    previous_filter_selected = 1;
                    if (holder.buttonLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        holder.buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            holder.nonVeg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listOrder = nonVegList;
                    if (nothingForThisCategory.isShown())
                        nothingForThisCategory.dismiss();
                    if (listOrder.size() == 0) {
                        nothingForThisCategory = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Nothing is present for this category", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                        nothingForThisCategory.show();
                    }
                    previous_filter_selected = 2;
                    if (holder.buttonLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        holder.buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            holder.filterLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (holder.buttonLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        holder.buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    else if (holder.buttonLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                        holder.buttonLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void dateClicked(String dateValueSelected) {
    mealTypeListForSelectDate = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mealTypeList.size(); i++) {
        if (dateValueSelected.equals(mealTypeList.get(i).get(Constants.DATE))) {
            mealTypeListForSelectDate.add(mealTypeList.get(i));
            previous_view_selected = 0;
            Constants.dateSelected = dateValueSelected;
        }
    }
}

private void addingMealTypeLayoutToUI(RecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, LayoutInflater vi) {
    try {
        holder.mealtype_layout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < mealTypeListForSelectDate.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> mealtype_hashmap = mealTypeListForSelectDate.get(i);

            mealTypeViewArray[i] = vi.inflate(R.layout.meal_type_name_layout, null);

            final TextView myButton = (TextView) mealTypeViewArray[i].findViewById(R.id.mealTypeTextView);
            String mealType = mealtype_hashmap.get(Constants.MEAL_TYPE);


            myButton.setText(mealType);
            myButton.setTag(mealtype_hashmap.get(Constants.MEALTYPE_MENUID));
            if (i == previous_view_selected) {
                myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.header_meal_type_selected);
                myButton.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.ColorPrimaryDark));
                mealTypeClicked(myButton.getTag().toString(), i);
            } else {
                myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.header_meal_type_not_selected);
                myButton.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Description));
            }

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            lp.topMargin = 10;
            lp.weight = 1;
            holder.mealtype_layout.addView(mealTypeViewArray[i], lp);

            final int finalI = i;
            myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mealTypeClicked(myButton.getTag().toString(), finalI);
                }
            });
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

private void mealTypeClicked(String mealTypeMenuId, int index) {

    try {
        if (!previous_meal_type_id.equals(mealTypeMenuId)) {

            Constants.mealTypeMenuIdSelected = mealTypeMenuId;
            List<MenuDescription> MealType_list = new ArrayList<>();
            vegList.clear();
            nonVegList.clear();

            previous_view_selected = index;

            for (int i = 0; i < globalList.size(); i++) {
                if (mealTypeMenuId.equals(globalList.get(i).getMenu_id())) {
                    MealType_list.add(globalList.get(i));
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < MealType_list.size(); i++) {
                if (MealType_list.get(i).getCatId().equals("true")) {
                    vegList.add(MealType_list.get(i));
                } else if (MealType_list.get(i).getCatId().equals("false")) {
                    nonVegList.add(MealType_list.get(i));
                }
            }
            try {
                completeList = MealType_list;

                if (previous_filter_selected == 0)
                    listOrder = completeList;
                else if (previous_filter_selected == 1)
                    listOrder = vegList;
                else if (previous_filter_selected == 2)
                    listOrder = nonVegList;
                previous_meal_type_id = mealTypeMenuId;
                mealTypeIdSelectedBeforeCartOpened = previous_meal_type_id;
                indexBeforeCartOpened = index;

                if (nothingForThisCategory.isShown())
                    nothingForThisCategory.dismiss();
                if (listOrder.size() == 0) {
                    nothingForThisCategory = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Nothing is present for this category", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                    nothingForThisCategory.show();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != listOrder ? listOrder.size() + 1 : 0);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (isPositionHeader(position))
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}


private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
    return position == 0;
}
```

}

Comment: I have also tried recomputing the list before if condition in `onBindView()`, that seems to work but sometimes through `indexOutOfBoundException` stating inconsistency detected.